# Reduce Scala AST to simplest equivalent AST

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I want to write a macro that needs to know (at compile time) the actual value of it's argument. If the user calls it in this way:

```
mymacro(42)
```

then the tree passed to the macro would be `Literal(Constant(42))`, and the macro could pattern-match like this:

```
tree match { case Literal(Constant(x: Int)) => x }
```

I would *not* expect to know the value of any arbitrary expression:

```
mymacro(40 + numWindowsOpen())  // not allowed; macro should fail at compile time
```

However, I would like to allow expressions like this:

```
val answer = 42   // val is immutable
mymacro(answer)
```

where the tree is `Ident(TermName("answer"))`, or like this:

```
mymacro(40 + 2)
```

where the tree is `Apply(Select(Literal(Constant(40)), TermName("$plus")), List(Literal(Constant(2))))`.

**Question: Is there any way to simplify all three of the statically-computable examples above to the same form?**

My claim is that all three trees are in some sense *equivalent* to each other.

I know that it's possible to evaluate a tree at compile time, e.g.:

```
val tree = q"40 + 2"

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
toolbox.eval(tree)  // returns 42
```

This may be an option, but it is somewhat unsatisfactory because any side-effects in the expression will be executed at compile time. Indeed, it would possibly even return a value for the tree of `40 + numWindowsOpen()`, which intuitively is not intended to be a static value.